# How to display a window larger than the display

Tags: 20.04, display, window

My laptop has a rather small display and for some programs, the windows do not fit the display or some window content is cut off if the window has the maximum size that fits the display. For the second case you can drag the window down on the display by clicking and dragging on the top window bar so that it partially disappears at the display bottom. Then you can make it higher by clicking at the window top border and dragging it up. Then the window is higher than the display, but you only can see the upper part of the window, as you cannot drag it upwards over the top border of the screen if you click and drag on the top window bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can drag the window outside of the top border by pressing the "window action key", clicking somewhere into the window and then dragging it. In my case the "window action key" was the "Windows" key on my keyboard ("Super-key") , but with the Gnome Tweaks app (German:  "Optimierungen"), it could be changed to be the Alt key or deactivated. Then you can see also the lower part of a window that is higher than the display.